# Swift - How to call a function after a function is complete?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am new in swift.
I have been trying to google around.

My question is, how can i call a function after a function is complete?
So far i am using a delay, but sometimes the delay is not in sync.

The problem i try to solve is to download a URL from firebase database, and then proceed to download a image from Firebase.

Comment: Read about completion blocks in Swift. That's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This looks like what you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685777/firebase-retrieve-image-from-url-save-with-firebase-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a closure.

```
func funcA() {
    funcB(){
        //Manage completion handler
    }
}

func funcB(completion: () -> Void) {
    completion()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Short and easy! Just what i needed!